# How to handle columns with large/infinte values in dataset for ML classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, missing-data

Computed a column using a formula (formula does't involve any log functions, just a group by with `.sum()`), but as expected this column would result in `infinite/exponential values` like below:

```
-inf
 nan
 inf
-3.000e+32
 7.3297+23 ...etc (similar data)
```

My doubt is how should I handle this column as `I could also not avoid this column for prediction` for a binary classification problem. What are the techniques to use before using this column in model classifier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a bit on the model you are going to run. I will explain a bit for Linear Models and for Decision trees ensembling (gradient boosting and random forest)

**Decision tree**

Not much to do, when the tree is built each branch will choose a split. If there is any information gain with a large value, it will choose it and make a split.

Some implementations, as catboost have a quantization in it. The split could be done eventually in something like 95% quantile and that will work with large values.

**Generalized Linear Models**

You will need to change this. My suggestion is creating a feature based in the values of the column (if df.col1> 9999: 1 else 0).
And then [Winsorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing) by a certain threshold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Carlos Mougan! If I'm going to start with Logistic Regression, once I do this `if df.col1> 9999: 1 else 0`, that feature column would have `0's or 1's`, how can I decide on the limits for `winsorizing` as per [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html)

Comment: It's a parameters, you can optimize parameters in Cross Validation or if you are not sure how to create a custom pipeline and crossvalidate with it, you can just try and error. There is not much theory behind this, it is just experimental.

Comment: Done! @Carlos Mougan, thanks!